# MySQL split on \

Tags: mysql

Is there another way to do the following operation in mysql?

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(membername, ' ', 1), ' ', -1)
```

I am basically trying to do the following in python:

```
str.split(' ')[-1]
```

Comment: Don't do string operations in your database. Do such things in your application code. Leave to the server do what it does best i.e. fetch the data fast. Don't add overhead that could be on the expense of other connections. My 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

No need for two `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, not sure why I originally had that. Here is what I used:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '\\', -1) from home_isilonpath
```